Installing Ubuntu 22.04 on USB Pendrive on Legacy system
I am new to Ubuntu, I already installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a USB pendrive and everything was fine because the system is Eufi. I tried many times to install Ubuntu on USB pendrive to use it on a Legacy Core2Duo system, to no avail. I want to know how the pendrive will be partitioned and what flags I need to assign to those partitions? Thanks

Do you have Ubuntu or grub on old system? I was able to add a BIOS boot stanza on 2006 Core2 Duo system and boot my external SSD that is in UEFI mode. BIOS boot from system bypassed UEFI boot. Actual install is same, only grub is different. I find with old system SSD much better/faster. If using BIOS version of grub, you can use gpt, but need a 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. Or use old MBR partitioning, no extra partitions required, just / (root). When first changing to UEFI, I would add both bios_grub & ESP - efi system partition to all gpt drives, so could convert grub.

The MBR used by a legacy system is outside of the partitioned area (ie. partitioning starts at sector 1, sector 0 being reserved since 1982 for MBR thus isn't touched by anything partitioning or flags). How you wrote the ISO to media will influence the install; you don't mention product (Server? Desktop?) thus we don't know installer, let alone how ISO was written, nor type of partition table you're using (thus if flags matter or will be ignored!)

Do you mean install a full OS onto a pen drive, or do you mean simply write an ISO onto a pen drive so that you can boot from it and install? If the latter, don't bother. Just use Ventoy to format a key, then copy as many ISO files as you want and will fit onto it. Quicker, easier, and it works on both legacy BIOS and UEFI computers.
https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

No I mean to have a full installation but instead of installing it on a hard drive, to install it on a usb pendrive.

It's pretty tricky but it can be done. I blogged about how some years ago: https://liam-on-linux.livejournal.com/50416.html
